# Raycast with PointerEventData (RaycastUI)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Following this(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptmum1FXiLE) tutorial from Code Monkey, I've got this code:

```
private bool ifUIItemIsHit()
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        pointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> raycastResultList = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerEventData, raycastResultList);
        for (int i = 0; i < raycastResultList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (raycastResultList[i].gameObject.tag == "UIItem")
            {
                raycastResultList.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return raycastResultList.Count > 0;
    }
```

What I expect is, that if I'm hovering over a gameobject with the tag 'UIItem' the bool returns true.

But it doesn't work as wished:
It still is true even if I'm only hovering over the parent and not the Image that has the tag.
How to fix that?

Comment: what exactly is not working? I what did debugging show you.

Comment: Like said in the post: the bool is true even thought I'm only hovering over the parent of the Image that has the tag and not the Image.

Comment: Raycastall  returns  all things under it. So are you sure you aren’t picking up background items? Try printing out all the items left after the loop

Comment: So its also traditional to go from end to beginning when deleting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you described is just what I would expect reading  your code.
The function will return true if there is an object WITHOUT tag "UIItem" under mouse cursor. What behaviour do you expect?

```
return raycastResultList.Count > 0 && raycastResultList[0].gameObject.tag == "UIItem";
```

Maybe something like that? It should return true if the first object under mouse cursor have tag

Comment: Thanks, but I figured, I could just make it 
`
if (raycastResultList[i].gameObject.tag != "UIItem")
            {
                raycastResultList.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
`
and that works. :)

Comment: you could use `return raycastResultList.Any(raycast => raycast.gameObject.tag != "UIItem");` with `using System.Linq`